# How can I update my app UI when time( in hours) change

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app has a UITableView having 12 rows, whose cell text and height of row is set according to the time in hours, i.e. when clock is at 6 than show text only in 6th row of UITableview and increase the size of 6th row only, keeping rest of rows text hidden and their row height smaller.

I used NSDateComponents to get current time in Hours. The problem is when app loads first time , the rows position are shown correctly.
When app is operand and time changes at that time the UI don't update, i.e. row position do not change.
I think I need NSNotificationCentre to notify when change in hour takes place and then use it to update row position.

Can any one explain how I can do this?

Here are codes from my app.

**TimeInfo.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface TimeInfo : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger timeNow;
-(NSInteger)currentTimeInHour;
```

**TimeInfo.m**

```
#import "TimeInfo.mh"

@implementation TimeInfo

-(NSInteger)currentTimeInHour{
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:now];
    NSInteger hour = [components hour];
    return hour;
}

@end
```

**tableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TimeInfo.h"

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController


@property (nonatomic) NSInteger timeInHour;

@end
```

**tableViewController.m**

```
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *someArray;   
}

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    TimeInfo *first = [[TimeInfo alloc]init];
    self.timeInHour  = [first currentTimeInHour]; //call method to get time in hour

     someArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [someArray insertObject:@"19" atIndex:0 ];
    [someArray insertObject:@"20" atIndex:1 ];
    ...........................................
    [someArray insertObject:@"45" atIndex:12]; // this is just for example, though I am loading data in array from plist. //not shown here.

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return somerArray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];


    if (self.timeInHour <= 12) {
        NSInteger firstHalf = self.timeInHour - 1;
        if (indexPath.row == firstHalf) {
            cell.textLabel.text = someArray[firstHalf]
        }

    } else if (self.timeInHour > 12){
        NSInteger secondHalf = self.timeInHour -13;
        if (indexPath.row == secondHalf) {
            cell.textLabel.text = someArray[secondHalf];
        }
    }
        return cell;
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   __block int blockValue =  45; //this is height for all the row except one which will be set from inside block and will match the cellForRowAtIndex method also// value will get changed from inside block.

    void (^tableRowHeightForThisHour)(void) = ^{

        if (self.timeInHour <= 12) {
            NSInteger firstHalf = self.timeInHour - 1;
            if (indexPath.row == firstHalf) {
                blockValue = 172;
            }

        } else if (self.timeInHour > 12){
            NSInteger secondHalf = self.timeInHour -13;
            if (indexPath.row == secondHalf) {
                blockValue = 172;
        }
    }

    }; //block ends here.

    tableRowHeightForThisHour();
    return blockValue;
}
```

Comment: Instead of calling it in viewDidLoad, Call it in ViewDidAppear and call reload tableView.

Comment: It's same result, since this code is only checking for time when it first launches. If app persist and time changes in-between, change is not being conveyed. I  need some way to notify that time has changed, so time to update the table view row position accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'd handle this is as follows:

1. Replace the `TimeInfo` class with a category on `NSDate` - the functionality you want is best thought of as an extension to `NSDate`.  Something like:

   ```
   @interface NSDate (currentHourInDay)
   -(NSInteger)currentHourInDay;
   @end
   ```

   (.h file)

   ```
   #import "NSObject+currentHourInDay.h"

   @implementation NSDate (currentHourInDay)

   -(NSInteger)currentHourInDay {
     NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
     NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:self];
     NSInteger hour = [components hour];
     return hour;
   }

   @end
   ```

   (.m file)

   This is basically the same as your method, but renamed to make it      slightly clearer what it does. (currentTimeInHour could mean 'number of seconds/mins through the hour' as well as 'current time in hours).  You'll 
   obviously need to import this into your VC to use it.

   You should also change the name of the property on your table view controller to `hourInDay`
2. Create an `NSTimer`, to fire every minute (or however long an interval you want between checks). Ideally, put it in a property.

   ```
   @property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer* timer;
   ```

   Start it up, with some appropriate values. Remember that starting a timer schedules it on the runloop, which retains the timer object. This means that it will keep on firing even if the object where the scheduling happened is deallocated. If you need to stop it when the object deallocs, or is no longer in use, you can do this using `[_timer invalidate]` in some appropriate place e.g. `dealloc` or `viewWillDisappear:` - this is why you need a property.

   ```
   NSTimeInterval minuteInSecs = 60.0;
   _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:minuteInSecs target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
   ```

   Note that it's timerFired: NOT timerFired. If you miss the colon out it will not work - it means that the selector takes an argument.
3. Implement the callback for the timer on the same object. In it, just check if the hour has changed, If it has, update `hourInDay` and reload the table. If it hasn't, do nothing.

   ```
   -(void)timerFired:(NSTimer*)timer {
     int newHourInDay = [[NSDate date] currentHourInDay];
     if(newHourInDay != self.hourInDay) {
       self.hourInDay = newHourInDay;  
       [self.tableView reloadData];
     }
   }
   ```

Your existing logic should handle the rest

Comment: How come I forgot NSTimer.   This did work, thanks a bunch for this broad explanation. Agree with creating Category. Do you think this can be done by using NSNotificationCentre.